# Changing images with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a game in which based on the choice the player makes, it will bring up new text to choose from. I'm trying to connect images to that text so they pull up with every choice. Right now, my text is working, but my images are no pulling up.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
    const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
    const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option- 
     buttons')
    
    let state = {}

    function startGame() {
        state = {}
        showTextNode(1)
                         }

      function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) { 
     const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === 
     textNodeIndex)
      textElement.innerText = textNode.text
      document.getElementById('img').src=textNode.img
      while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
      
   optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
        }

        textNode.options.forEach(option => {
            if (showOption(option)) {
            const button = document.createElement('button')
            button.innerText = option.text
            button.classList.add('btn')
            button.addEventListener('click', () => 
            selectOption(option))
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
                }
            })
         }

        function showOption(option) {
        return option.requiredState == null || 
        option.requiredState(state)
            }

        function selectOption(option) {
        const nextTextNodeId = option.nextText
        if (nextTextNodeId <= 0) {
        return startGame()
            }
        state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)
        showTextNode(nextTextNodeId)
            }
      
        const textNodes = [
        {
        id: 1,
        Image:url('invitation.jpg'),
        text: "You are cordially invited to celebrate Sir Troy 
        Bennet's 70th birthday! RSVP to attend the event this 
        evening at the Cherry Hill mansion.",
        options: [
        {
        text: 'RSVP',
        nextText: 2
        },
        {
        text: "I'm going to stay home",
        nextText: 24
        }
         ]
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to need more context such as a reproducable example on JSFIDDLE or CODEPEN... however based on what I can see your code says;

```
textNode.img
```

When you are looking for;

```
textNode.Image
```

On line 17;

```
document.getElementById('img').src=textNode.img
```

So you have to change `Image:url('invitation.jpg'),` to be `img:url('invitation.jpg'),` or update `textNode.img` to be `textNode.Image` as mentioned above.

Comment: hey, thanks so much for commenting. I implemented the change, but it still didn't pull up the image. Adding a JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/lazytitan97/sz2dp0eu/

Comment: @lazyTitan91 - casing is important. You did ``textNode.image`` rather than ``textNode.Image`` - you are also using a DIV, DIV's cannot support images using ``document.getElementById('img').src`` - so change that IMG div to be; ``<img id="img" src="">`` - https://jsfiddle.net/xzjmb5pr/

Comment: @lazyTitan91 also your code is really inconsistent. In some places you call it ``Image`` in others it's ``Img`` - you need to be consistent.

Comment: @dDexterians Thank you for helping out! I'm super tired so I missed some spots. Fixed and working now. Super appreciate it!